# Как скрутить дизлайки на youtube?

Tags: youtube

Дело обстоит так:

19.12.2019 прошла пресс конференция Президента. Админы телеканала "России 24" выложили [4 часа Большой Пресс-конференции Президента РФ Владимира Владимира Путина на yoututbe.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlKw6E4n_Xc)

В комментариях люди жаловались (неоднократно), что

*"как только дизлайков становится 50 000 (иногда 51 000), их скручивают до 45000 (46, 47) и т.д."*

Я в такой бред поверить не мог, но комментов было так много, что я сам решил понаблюдать за явлением.

Я замерил (без скринов) динамику добавления лайков и дизлайков.

```
 МСК 22;21  19/12/2019
 Лайков - 14 083 
 Дизлайков 50 722
 Просмотров 683 317
```

за 15 минут:

```
 Лайков + 95
 Дизлайков +1 237
 Просмотров + 14 218
```

На каждый лайк, ставили 11 - 12 дизлайков. В 22:23 скрутили 1442 дизлайка:

```
МСК 22;23 
Лайков 14 101 (+18) 
Дизлайков 49 328 (-1 442) 
Просмотров 683 938 (+621)
```

23:08 скрин [image: Лайков 14 366]
По состоянию на 23:08

```
14 366   
51 970
```

[image: 23:38 cкрин]

В 23:38 (или около того) дизлайки скрутили!

```
14 527   
51 042
```

В 23:44 ещё крутанули дизлайки вниз:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В 23:44 картина такая 
    14 583 (+55)   
     50 053 (-991!!!)

Предположим, вы ставите мои данные под сомнение, тогда я вам предлагаю простой эксперимент: зайдите по ссылке, снимите два показателя через две минуты и посчитайте, насколько приросли лайки и дизлайки. Мне кажется, что соотношение лайков и дизлайков в любой релевантный промежуток времени будет не меньше чем 10 дизлайков на один лайк.

**Выглядит происками врагов, но у меня простые вопросы:**

Какие есть способы скрутки дизлайков? И какой способ скрутки, на ваш взгляд, использовали заинтересованные стороны? Может всему есть прозаичное объяснение, типа "сервак на youtube лагает из за высокого трафика"?

Comment: Я не уверен, что это подходящая тема для so, тут нет ничего о программировании. Но могу дать ответ в комментариях, тут всё просто и те кто в теме знают о такой фишке. Ютуб даёт возможность списывать дизлайки, поэтому в острых политических темах специально онлайн сидят специально обученые люди, которые через некоторое время подают на апелляцию и списывают дизлайки.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что явно не по теме.

Comment: @eanmos возможно вы правы, что не по теме, но русский SO отличается от английского тем, что здесь действительно часть вопросов не по программированию. К примеру в Английском в отдельные разделы вынесены железо, биткоины, software quality и много другое. https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology
Так что связи со сложившейся ситуацией, мне кажется что вопросы про то, как работают те или иные механизмы популярных сайтов вполне допустимы.

Comment: @AK вы похоже понимаете как это работает. Может правда дадите развернутый ответ со ссылками на доки youtube и описание процесса, хотя бы с ссылками на английские первоисточники? Реально мне интересно разобраться, как это работает по шагам. Реально очень надо. Будет здорово, если вы опишите по подробнее. Хочу чтобы вы написали буквальный механизм процесса типа такого: 
1. Зашли хомяки, поставили дизлайки
2. Зашёл дядя Петя, настрочил жалобу
3. Админ youtube рассмотрел жалобу, (и мне хочется понять, как они всё сделали настолько оперативно), принял решение скрутить на 10% дизлайки.

Comment: Это тема для хабра не для so

Comment: Вопрос абсолютно согласуется с правилами и тематикой данного форума. Все минусы вызванны исключительно политическими симпатиями к упомянутому в вопросе персонажу, но, по своей сути, вопрос технический и относится к реинженирингу ютуба. Единственная притензия, что автор в начале использовал выражение "Кощей Бессмертный" (исправленно), имеющего негативную коннотацию, думаю, если бы использовал нейтральное "Сказочный Персонаж", минусов было бы меньше ;)

Comment: Взял на себя смелость отредактировать вопрос, так, чтобы он звучал политически нейтрально (политике здесь не место!) во всем остальном вопрос ни в чем не правилам ru.stackoverflow, думаю, можно восстановить

Comment: @asianirish я не против любой редакции. Меня при обращении на SO интересовал механизм, а не политика.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin ну и я о том же. Для этого и отредактировал, чтобы не было повода закрывать

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, я сам с большим интересом прочитал этот вопрос и ответ на него. Он не по теме, его закрыли. Ответ на него получен. Все счастливы, все довольны :)

Comment: @eanmos ну я поставил автору галочку, потому что был не в курсе, можно ли будет принять ответ после закрытия. Но объективно лучше бы вопрос был бы открыт - вдруг кто-то точнее знает в чём причина.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, если кто-то знает точнее, он напишет об этом в комментариях.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как не странно ответ может быть очень прост. Моё мнение основано на своём личном опыте, который ради интереса вы можете проделать сами потратив буквально минут 20.Платформа YouTube может сама снимать те или иные параметры видео ролика, это может быть лайки, дизлайки, просмотры. Списывать могут за то, что происходит накрутка, или же пользователи сами под управление кого-то (например "рейд от стримера") заходят ставят диз и закрывают сразу, YouTube это считает как за накрутку и может по ошибке списать. Для провидения теста найдите самый просто накрутчик в интернете (например вкм**с(не реклама!!! Сервис такой себе и т.д)) Далее попробуйте залить ролик и накрутить около 50-100 лайков и через 15 минут YouTube большую часть спишет автоматически.

Comment: вы знаете, звучит правдоподобно. Тэзис что youtube продался мне кажется маловероятным. У них столько денег нет.

Comment: Я привел лишь пример из своего личного опыта, когда пытался раскручивать свои видео на YouTube, ибо зная алгоритмы YouTube, плохие сервисы очень плохо воздействую с YouTube.  На счет конкретного случая я больше чем уверен, что это просто люди узнали что все решили ставить дизы и произошел эффект "рейда от стримера" как я говорил уже ранее, когда пользователи просто заходят ставят дизлайк и просто уходят. Так что никаких скруток дизлайков и т.д нету.